# on the definition of $H^\infty$-diffeomorphisms

Tags: sobolev-spaces, diffeomorphism

The group of orientation-preserving $H^\infty$-diffeomorphisms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as

$$\operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{\operatorname{id}+f\,|\,f\in H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\text{ and } \det(\operatorname{id}+df)>0 \}$$
where
$$H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)=\bigcap_{q\geq0}H^q(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n).$$
is the intersection of all Sobolev spaces $H^q(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I need an explanation for and/or motivation for this definition. To me, elements of $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are just smooth (in the weak sense) functions that decay to the identity at infinity. However, elements of $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ ought to be invertible with smooth inverse.

$\textbf{
1. Why are functions of the form $\operatorname{id}+f$ with $f\in H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ invertible and what is the inverse?}$
I've looked here: [Inverse of a sum of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158479/inverse-of-a-sum-of-functions), and it doesn't appear there is a general rule for the inverse of a sum of functions.

$\textbf{2. Why define elements of $\operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as shifts of the identity to begin with? Why not just define}$

$$\operatorname{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{f\in H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\,|\,f^{-1}\in H^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\text{ and } \det(\operatorname{id}+df)>0 \}?$$

This definition is given [in this paper,](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272398/1-s2.0-S0022039615X00027/1-s2.0-S0022039614004574/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQD9YUzMup2ksYR8UCluqU558zF4mkWqJPpgCS3DYGVk1wIgIZVBsMiAQHQ6%2FnglufKkn5rA3yq%2BGmdu25z2IECwCbAqvAUIsf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDP9tuUsOOTL1avmGJiqQBdp9dhsaMU0YK9MHrMhppJk79DkQBVV6wPihOXtzLVw48U1euNaj21Wi56S6UDD1OGYTc5uyI2hktWnRZJDBxxu8jIwgFTYEC2DlbImvJ9Y5gYESYf%2F1740DOQwNsBORPdm8sEqjSnsJDDXAkW9mszI78fuKhT1h6qkOaaKghuPxFBCeAkAVjyclTU0dTuJimqwaRoD9q7gW3JUxvGqcOsrBpqIOphItgW8tVEnEWMDO823OWySGJ9Q4p5aT%2FOUDDpkVmFywg1bfb2Em6Ivpet3jv4AH3d40hi4yXpwU1Dxl36gHwII3zQswzsTWCpwflijrpdMHD%2Bteus8ZTFBnoDzJcAIQvr3ZLn4CZA%2BPkImmMzg2JMmXtYrfe3nzwYCxXfYD2uWxPR5MSMdF1FblVh1LbTWRdovJDQo2fkcVVQvbt8JCekBXhxdQW4RZOnTkybU3gXPPc5jQBviJkqrbR748r%2FuVP7o4lQ82Qk0GqPSKJMBpW7FHSVRal%2BQBsg%2F5d7ujYyaN78S%2FsbVgi5bSpxQuDyQa%2BdRp%2Fkmlh3yFdnCP1hDowmPzQDMNTnhUAM9042JMUzbYL43UhQsKZCFnMoF783BGbY3IP0Xorc4dCdF1RWwAD5a8MS0cV%2ByLDhSRyj1wvVw1GXooUaJ%2FWoYWHOvc29AsOx6xAFpVSIXYdakczEqWBSEQ7FooR%2BiKRKdEDJMcsj%2F%2BY1KuKQ6GPkJitNDp6hwdHENCfJ78nV%2BYDy9SNND0ksnuW2MHeNIXSND0puqWzJRmnhPG%2BNKalensYg0KjOJ%2FfAT2pOIp%2Bn%2FMoZ2%2FrhAlIT0mWHNUCDJn6IZHwmB0%2FESPNTxULw5dD%2BROyvLu64hBbAZYcNZttSCXrNr3MNnW2K8GOrEBURYkrI014qLJvBIbe9hFQ%2F8fBsrX9lfJBFoGXQ3rKenCFvqsA5KDMHmIaKM%2F1NUtKjlK07rrZNFAweIy6NtWVBk%2BE%2FkgMrHUdNwikUWuaUjxfDR1c4qNN314xJPD3ahvCFc3Sqb7aVjumbuMyjtav%2BkmnTTbQDc%2Fr0a%2F12gfPIPYUo9OHbtWiYrcwt1FA1b5UB9RBRuLsXO1cgAicXuSmnfhVrJJePPV0P2TMA6UOEqV&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20240317T012334Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY6IMM36MI%2F20240317%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=f3f15eb36acf0b3fb199a9e1e39f03ebbfe580cc9aa71e64fb90b8d17a64ba65&hash=17954b2c3c28c0dca9180989b7644bfcaf1ac52650dd6100aadbbe1bca6cf9ce&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022039614004574&tid=spdf-c7416586-db8f-4681-b7f7-4d00e77b4a17&sid=b2a1c4221ae6a247970859f7a429d7024fb7gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=1b125a525356550106&rr=86592da98c8552a0&cc=us) at the beginning of section 2, or [in this paper,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.5704.pdf) under heading 3.4.

Comment: Where did you see this definition?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I've added links to two papers in OP.

Comment: I just noticed that the "Zoo of diffeomorphisms" paper answers my first question at the end of page 7.